# Make a selection menu in a linux script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to create users
create_users() {
    echo "Enter the full path of the user file:"
    read user_file

    # Check if the file exists
    if [ -f "$user_file" ]; then
        while IFS=, read -r username full_name password main_group work_dir; do
            # Create the user
            sudo useradd -m -p "$password" -g "$main_group" -d "$work_dir" "$username"

            # Create the user's personal directories
            sudo mkdir "$work_dir/documents"
            sudo mkdir "$work_dir/images"
            sudo mkdir "$work_dir/videos"
            sudo mkdir "$work_dir/music"

            # Set appropriate permissions for the personal directories
            sudo chown "$username:$main_group" "$work_dir/documents"
            sudo chown "$username:$main_group" "$work_dir/images"
            sudo chown "$username:$main_group" "$work_dir/videos"
            sudo chown "$username:$main_group" "$work_dir/music"
            sudo chmod 700 "$work_dir/documents"
            sudo chmod 700 "$work_dir/images"
            sudo chmod 700 "$work_dir/videos"
            sudo chmod 700 "$work_dir/music"
        done < "$user_file"
        echo "Users have been created successfully."
    else
        echo "The user file does not exist."
    fi


# Function to delete users
delete_users() {
    echo "Enter the full path of the user file:"
    read user_file

    # Check if the file exists
    if [ -f "$user_file" ]; then
        while IFS=, read -r username _ _ _ _; do
            # Delete the user
            sudo userdel -r "$username"
        done < "$user_file"
        echo "Users have been deleted successfully."
    else
        echo "The user file does not exist."
    fi
}
```

How to make a selection/management menu for this.

Answer (score 1):

The next code should do, put it below the already written code

### Function to show the menu and manage options

```
show_menu() {
    while true; do
        echo "----- MENU -----"
        echo "1. Create Users"
        echo "2. Delete Users"
        echo "0. Exit"
        echo "----------------"
        echo "Enter an option:"
        read option

        case $option in
            1)
                create_users
                ;;
            2)
                delete_users
                ;;
            0)
                echo "Goodbye!"
                exit 0
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Invalid option. Please try again."
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

### Call the function to show the menu

```
show_menu
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a simple `select` loop instead of a `case` nested inside `while`?